# Small output glitch with Histogram

Tags: graphics, histograms, version-7

I'm experiencing a small formating glitch with an histogram.  I want to define an histogram with a ***square frame***, with precise *vertical ticks* from 0 to 10.  But I'm still getting a larger range, and I don't know why.  Here's a working code which shows the problem :

```
velocity[n_, r_] := velocity[n, r] = RandomReal[{0, 1}]
ca[n_, r_] := ca[n, r] = RandomReal[{-1, 1}]
phi[n_, r_] := phi[n, r] = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]

V0[n_, r_] := V0[n, r] = velocity[n, r] {
        Sqrt[1 - ca[n, r]^2] Cos[phi[n, r]],
        Sqrt[1 - ca[n, r]^2] Sin[phi[n, r]],
        ca[n, r]
    }

Manipulate[
    Histogram[ 
    Table[Norm[V0[n, r]], {n, 1, Np}], {0.05},
    ColorFunction -> Function[{height}, Opacity[height]],
    ChartStyle -> Purple,
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 10}},
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    Axes -> False,
    Frame -> True,
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    FrameLabel -> {
        Style["Velocity", 14],
        Style["Number of particles", 14]
    },
    ImageSize -> {500, 500}
    ],
    {{Np, 1, Style["N", 14, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 1, 100, 1},
    Delimiter,
    Row[{
        Button[Style["Randomizer", Bold, Red, 12], {r = RandomReal[]},
        Appearance -> "Palette",
        ImageSize -> {100, 24}
    ]
    }],
    ControlPlacement -> Bottom,
    FrameMargins -> None
]
```

So what am I doing wrong with this code ?

Comment: Is `PlotRangePadding -> 0` the answer?

Comment: @Kuba, nope, I'm still getting the same vertical range, from 0 to approx 11.

Comment: @Kuba, I pasted the option `PlotRangePadding -> 0` just under the `PlotRange`.  Is there something wrong with this ?

Comment: Try PlotRange->{{0, 1}, {0, 9.5}} and the top value is 10.

Comment: @bills, why is this ?  This is unpredictable.

Comment: @bills, I'm still getting the same output problem.  The vertical axes isn't from 0 up to 10.

Comment: @bills and Cham With `PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 9.5}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0...` I got exactly what I'd expect. Tested on 10.3 and 10.4 on Win7

Comment: @Kuba, so this may be a bug with my version ?  (MMA 7 here).  And why {0, 9.5} anyway ?

Comment: 'PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 10}}, PlotRangePadding -> False' works here (I.e., top of graph is at exactly 10), Mma 10.4.

Comment: Cham Can't test that. Let's wait for someone with V7 then. Gtg now.

Comment: Using `PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 10}}, PlotRangePadding -> False` give me the same output :  Vertical axes from 0 to 11, and the top horizontal line isn't drawn.

Comment: Cham, can you reduce this down to a *minimal* example? Can you generate a simple histogram (no dynamic, no buttons, no formatting) that reproduces your problem? For instance, on 10.4 `Histogram[RandomReal[{0, 10}, 100], PlotRange -> {0, 30}, PlotRangePadding -> None, Frame -> True]` [works as expected](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fwGEV.png). What happens on your system?

Comment: @MarcoB, the output I get from your MWE code still has too much space on the vertical axes.  It goes from 0 to about 33, instead of 30.

Comment: @Cham So I'm afraid that it's safe to assume that it is a problem with your version of MMA that has since been resolved. There is seemingly nothing wrong with the code, except perhaps adding `PlotRangePadding -> None`, and it is likely that you will then have to resort to manual adjustment of the axes as mentioned above.

Comment: @MarcoB, thanks, I agree that it's pretty clear now.  -1 for my MMA version !

Comment: I solved the issue !  Putting the Histogram inside a `Show[...]` apparently solves completely the output problem.

Comment: @Cham That is... interesting behavior :-) perhaps you could post a quick self answer indicating the problems and your workaround, so your question isn't left hanging.

Comment: As an alternative, `PlotRange->{{0,1},{0,9.5}}` gives the plot you're looking for.

Comment: @N.J.Evans, the problem is its unpredictable.  I need a precise setup for a `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by wrapping the `Histogram` inside a `Show` !  Here's an example which works very well with *Mathematica 7* :

```
(*This code produces the issue :  too much space above the vertical axes : *)
Histogram[
    RandomReal[{0, 10}, 100],
    PlotRange -> {0, 30},
    PlotRangePadding -> None,
    Frame -> True
]

(* This one solves the problem : *)
Show[
    Histogram[RandomReal[{0, 10}, 100]],
    PlotRange -> {0, 30},
    PlotRangePadding -> None,
    Frame -> True
]
```

Weird, isn't ?  The `PlotRangePadding -> None` is essential here.